# Getting log-likelihood from probabilistic suffix tree

Tags: markov-chains, pst, traminer, sequence-analysis

Here is my code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(TraMineR)
library(PST)

x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/08228977353bf6dc2edb3ec121f54a29/raw/c2539d06771317c5f4c8d3a2052a73fc485a09c6/challenge_level.csv")
data <- read.csv(text = x)

# Load and transform data
data <- read.table("thread_level.csv", sep = ",", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

data.seq <- seqdef(data[2:nrow(data),2:ncol(data)], missing = "NA", right = "*")

# Make a tree
S1 <- pstree(data.seq, ymin = 0.05, L = 6, lik = TRUE, with.missing = F)
logLik(S1)
```

For some reason, it refuses to return a Log-likelihood value? Why is this the case? How can I get a Log-likelihood value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bad values for the `missing` and `right` arguments in your `seqdef` command which then causes an error in `pstree`.

With

```
data.seq <- seqdef(data[2:nrow(data),2:ncol(data)], missing = NA, right= NA, nr = "*")
# Make a tree
S1 <- pstree(data.seq, ymin = 0.05, L = 6, lik = TRUE, with.missing = TRUE)
logLik(S1)
```

we get

```
'log Lik.' -31011.32 (df=47179)
```

Note that since you have missing values I have set `with.missing = TRUE` in the `pstree` command.

===============

To ignore the right missings, set `right='DEL'` in `seqdef`.

```
seq <- seqdef(data[2:nrow(data),2:ncol(data)], missing = NA, right= "DEL")
S2 <- pstree(seq, ymin = 0.05, L = 6, lik = TRUE, with.missing = F)
logLik(S2)
```

I don't know what PST computes as `logLik(S2)` and why we get here an `NA`. The likelihood to generate the data with the tree `S2` can be obtained by means of the `predict` function that returns the likelihood of each sequence in the data. The log likelihood of the data should then be

```
sum(log(predict(S2, seq)))
```

which gives

```
 [>] 984 sequence(s) - min/max length: 1/32
 [!] sequences have unequal lengths
 [>] max. context length: L=6
 [>] found 1020 distinct context(s)
 [>] total time: 0.588 secs
[1] -4925.79
```

Comment: However, all of my missing values are on the right--there's not a single missing value "inside" of the sequences. Hence, roughly 90% of all my events are `*`. Won't this skew the probabilities?

Comment: For example, when I do `cmine(S1, pmin = 0, state = "good_idea", l = 1)` I get a probability of `e` that is 47%--this should not even be possible with this dataset, since no sequence starts with `*`.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to ignore the missing end of the sequences. And, your are right, we get then an `NA` logLik. I suggest you ask the author of the package about what this `logLik` is supposed to be (it does not return the same value as the method I propose in the answer!).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, there was a problem when computing likelihood of models fitted to sequences of unequal lengths. This is fixed. The new version of the PST package (0.94) will be available within a few hours on R-Forge, to install:

```
install.packages("PST", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

and later on CRAN.

Note that since your sequences don't contain any missing values but are of unequal lengths, you don't have to set neither `with.missing=TRUE` when using the `pstree` function nor any option when using `seqdef`.

Now when running the following code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(TraMineR)
library(PST)

x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/08228977353bf6dc2edb3ec121f54a29/raw/c2539d06771317c5f4c8d3a2052a73fc485a09c6/challenge_level.csv")
data <- read.csv(text = x)

data.seq <- seqdef(data[2:nrow(data),2:ncol(data)])

# Make a tree
S1 <- pstree(data.seq, ymin = 0.05, L = 6)
```

I get:

```
> S1@logLik
[1] -4925.79
```

Comment: See comment in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968530/fitting-a-vlmc-to-very-long-sequences - not recognizing the missing values causes issues in `tune()` and `cmine()` - how can I get around this?